# Laravel8.x GoogleAPIによるログイン機能を実装しましたが、プロフィール画像をセッションに保存した際にbladeファイルで正しく表示できません

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, session

Googleアカウントからユーザー情報を受け取り、その中のプロフィール画像をセッションに保存してhtml上で表示したいのですが、インスペクタで確認したところ<img src(unknown)>と表示され、htmlでも正しく表示されません。

以下、コードです。

##### GoogleLoginController.php

```
public function handleGoogleCallback(Request 
$request)
    {
        // Google 認証後の処理
        $googleUser = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();

        
        $user = User::where([
            'email' => $googleUser->email,
            'name' => $googleUser->name
            ])
            ->first();

        // メールアドレスがDB内の情報と一致するか
        if ($user == null) {
            $user = $this->createUserByGoogle($googleUser);
        }

        Auth::login($user, $remember = true);
        $request->session()->push('users', $user->email); // 配列に保存
        $request->session()->push('admin', $user->admin);
        $request->session()->push('avatar', $googleUser->getAvatar());

        
        return redirect()
            ->route('index')
            ->with('flash_message', 'ログインしました');
    }
```

##### layout.blade.php

```
<?php $avatar_link = session()->get('avatar'); ?>

@if (session()->has('avatar'))
    <div class="account-icon">
        <button type="submit" onclick="location.href='{{ route('mypage') }}'"><img src="<?php $avatar_link ?>"></button>
    </div>
@else
    <div class="account-icon">
        <button type="submit" onclick="location.href='{{ route('mypage') }}'"><img src="{{ secure_asset('icon_tpl/man.png') }}"></button>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: `<?php $avatar_link = session()->get('avatar') ?>`  のように変数に代入して`<img src="{{ $avatar_link[0] }}">`として配列のindexを指定することで正しく画像が表示されました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

セッションを介すのが適切かはしりませんが、であれば

```
<img src="{{ session()->get('avatar') }}"></button>
```

などのようになりませんか？

Comment: ところで質問とは関係がないですがwhereに名前を入れるべきではなさそう

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。試したところ  
`htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given ...`と表示されてしまいました。'avatar'の値をstring型に変換して`<img src="{{ session()->get('avatar') }}>`に代入したいのですが、その方法がわからず詰まっています。

Comment: 解決しました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 何故か配列にされてましたね，ユースケース的には`$request->session()->push`ではなくて`$request->session()->put`でよさそうです